# Mysql to postgres Migration pgloader "ERROR mysql: 76 fell through ECASE expression"

Tags: data-migration, pgloader

While I try to migrate my MySQL Databse to a Postgres database.

I Face the Following Error.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You may find the solution found by user [Axxxolotl](https://github.com/Axxxolotl) in [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/913#issuecomment-945444747) useful:

> ```
> apt remove pgloader -y
> git clone https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader.git
> apt-get install sbcl unzip libsqlite3-dev make curl gawk freetds-dev libzip-dev
> cd /path/to/pgloader
> make pgloader
> ./build/bin/pgloader --help
> pgloader --debug mysql://root:'123'@127.0.0.1/nextcloud_storage postgresql://postgres:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/nextcloud_storage
> ```

You might need to replace the beginning of that last line with `./build/bin/pgloader` instead of `pgloader`. Either that, or run `make install` or similar.

Comment: After completing above steps:
I ran pgloader command and it is throwing 

Command 'pgloader' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install pgloader

Comment: Doing this dropped my in to some sort of lisp debugger that would not exit and had to be `kill -9`ed. Seriously, would not even stop with a normal `kill`

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by compiling `pgloader` from source.

Answer (score 0):

After completing above steps provided by @starball, if you're facing `Command 'pgloader' not found` add `./build/bin/pgloader` in the last step.
So final steps should look something like-

```
apt remove pgloader -y
git clone https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader.git
apt-get install sbcl unzip libsqlite3-dev make curl gawk freetds-dev libzip-dev
cd pgloader
make pgloader
./build/bin/pgloader --help
./build/bin/pgloader mysql://root:'123'@127.0.0.1/nextcloud_storage postgresql://postgres:pass@127.0.0.1:5432/nextcloud_storage
```